# Why Apache IoTDB reported `FragmentInstance is aborted by timeout` query error?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I wonder why this error happened in Apache IoTDB? The information is `Caused by: org.apache.iotdb.db.mpp.execution.schedule.FragmentInstanceAbortedException: FragmentInstance 20231114_020733_73751_1.1.0 is aborted by timeout`. There is a multi-threaded query in my code. Does this timeout mean that the data for this multi-threaded query are not queried?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the query timeout settings of Apache IoTDB and try again. I guess that you have queried all the data in the device dimension, and that's why this query got timeout and no result came back.